# cannot clone from gitlab repository

Tags: git, github, gitlab

i want to clone a project from a gitlab repo, but cannot do it. neither with ssh, nor the http address. What I did until now (using OS X 10.6.8)

1. install git 1.8.5.2
2. git init in a local directory gitrepos
3. tried git clone projectURL - doesnt work.
   (`git clone https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2` works)

error I get:

```
git clone http://....
Cloning into 'xyz'...
fatal: unable to access '....': Failed connect to ....; Operation timed out
```

Comment: Any solutions to this, please? I'm facing the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

If you tried with github and it works, this rules out a problem with your workstation.

Have you check the configuration of your gitlab server? (firewall, git daemon, etc.)